# Sort and separate names from a database

Tags: javascript, sql, database

Could anybody point me in the right direction?

I have a database with a handful of messages. Each message has a username also..

I wish to use the names of the messages in a drop down menu so that the user can click a user and view the messages from the user.

**THE PROBLEM**: the drop down list shows every user of every message and i don-not know how to separate the users so that if there is 7 messages from ROB only 1 ROB will be shown in the drop down list..

I hope I am making sense here.

So if anyone could help me here, I would be grateful.

What sort of query should I be using the separate every user from the database so I can show them in the drop-down menu, as individual users...

Instead of the same user being shown for as many messages as the user wrote.

Below is the current query..

```
<div class='userbox'>
<header class='ubheader'>Contacts</header>
<section class='ubmain'>
";


    $db = new PDO("mysql:host=localhost;dbname=messages", 'root', ''); // 1. set database with this instead of conect - or change conect to this

    $query="SELECT * FROM `messagedatabase` WHERE `listID`='$listID' ORDER BY messagedate DESC";

    $stat=$db->prepare($query);

    $stat->execute();
        $Mcount = $stat->rowCount();
        $messagecount=$Mcount;

        while($row = $stat->fetch()){
             $messageaccountname=$row['messageaccountname'];

                if ($messageaccountname != $useraccountname){
                            echo"<div class='ubnames' onclick='selectmessage(\"{$messageaccountname}\")'>{$messageaccountname}</div>";  
                }
        }



echo "
</section>

</div>
";
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Many thanks.

Answer (score 1):

The simple solution would be to add a DISTINCT clause to your query, such as:
`SELECT DISTINCT messageaccountname FROM ....`

Beyond that, it sounds like the database isn't normalized.  Ideally, you'd have your accounts in a separate table that would be related to your `messagedatabase` table.  But database design is a different discussion beyond the scope of this post.